# Proving convergence of the p-harmonic series by showing that it is Cauchy (p=2)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove convergence of the p-harmonic series
$$
1 +\frac{1}{2^p} +\frac{1}{3^p} +\frac{1}{4^p}+…
$$
using the Cauchy criterion, i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0\  \exists N:n,m>N \implies |S_n-S_m|<\epsilon$, where
$$
S_n= 1 +\frac{1}{2^p} +…+\frac{1}{n^p}.
$$
I have seen proofs of convergence of the p-harmonic series using the Cauchy Condensation Theorem or the Euler solution to the Basel problem, however I could not come up with a choice of $N$ that allows to use the simple Cauchy criterion for complete spaces.
If a general solution could not be provided, I would be more than happy to obtain the one for $p=2$.

Comment: The case $p=2$ is well known as the Basel-problem (sum is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$) , and for $p>2$, the case $p=2$ is a majorant.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the integral-criterion ? This would make a proof much easier.

Comment: Simplest proof uses comparison with $\int_n^{m}\frac  1 {x^{p}}dx$.

Comment: Various proofs here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/235574/42969

Comment: For $p=2$ see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611589/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us prove that the sequence $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and we will define $N\in\mathbb{N}$ as $N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right\rceil$. Than for all $m>n>N$ we can observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\left|S_n-S_m\right|=&\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}\right|=\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\\
\\
=&\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\leq\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$
as wanted.

Comment: (+1) can $p>2$ be done by comparison?

Comment: Hi @violet Flame, yes, for $p>2$ you can prove the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ by the comparison test, but the question was to prove that when $p=2$ the partial sums are Cauchy sequence. for the general case one can even prove that the series  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent if and only if $p>1$ using Cauchy condensation test, or using other tests. i am recommending that you will look at the link in Martin R comment in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For $p=2$ we can do this:
$$
\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n(n-1)} = \frac{1}{n-1} -\frac{1}{n}
$$
and use a finite telescoping sum to prove the Cauchy criterion.
For $1<m<n$,
$$
S_n - S_m = \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} < 
\sum_{k=m+1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1} -\frac{1}{k}\right)
=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{m}.
$$

Comment: It may be interesting to investigate the sort-of telescoping property for $1/(n(n-1)(n-2))$ to do the series $\sum 1/n^3$.

Comment: Why can’t you show $p>2$ using comparison with $(p=2)$?

Comment: (+1) btw, it’s a great answer,  it I wonder why the general case can’t be done by comparison.

Comment: The cases $p>2$ can, of course, be done by comparison with the case $p=2$.